# Error when using a custom metric function in Keras

Tags: python, keras, metrics

I have issues when trying to use a custom function to compile a lstm model in Keras.

I have defined a custom metric function called `mean_p_e` and I want to use it in my model built in Keras.

My code is:

```
import keras.backend as K
def mean_p_e(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean((y_true - y_pred)**2/y_true)
```

Then I build my model, stored in a json file:

```
"model": {
    "loss": "mse",
    "optimizer": "adam",
    "save_dir": "saved_models",
    "metric":"mean_p_e",
```

and I compile:

```
model.compile(loss=configs['model']['loss'], optimizer=configs['model']['optimizer'], metrics=['accuracy', configs['model']['metric']])
```

And I get the Following error:

> ValueError: Unknown metric function:mean_p_e

What do I need to change to make it works?

Comment: It seems your json file is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you define `configs` in the same script, just replace `"metric":"mean_p_e"` with `"metric":mean_p_e` in `configs`, then everything works.

But it seems that `configs` is something you read from a json file, in this situation, you could try:

```
model.compile(loss=configs['model']['loss'], 
              optimizer=configs['model']['optimizer'], 
              metrics=['accuracy', locals()[configs['model']['metric']]])
```

or:

```
model.compile(loss=configs['model']['loss'], 
              optimizer=configs['model']['optimizer'], 
              metrics=['accuracy', eval(configs['model']['metric'])])
```

to call a function by its name.

Ref: [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string).